# Как работать с запросами в Python

Tags: python, веб-скрейпинг

Я провожу парсинг сайта с авторизацией, когда я захожу на сайт в Network мне прилетает два запроса, один html, другой json, когда я начинаю парсить с помощью кода, сайт мне отдает только html,как мне забрать json?

```
user_info = passwrd
login = user_info[0]
password = user_info[1]
try:
    session = requests.Session()
    link = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/login/index.php'
    user = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': user.random
    }

response = session.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
login_token = soup.find('input', {'name': "logintoken"})['value']

data = {
    "logintoken": login_token,
    "username": login,
    "password": password
}
response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)

profile_info = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/lib/ajax/service.php?sesskey=Rs62OJwrPr&info=core_calendar_get_action_events_by_timesort'
profile_response = session.get(profile_info, headers=headers)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(profile_response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup1)
# infa = soup1.select_one('.action-menu-trigger')
# infa1 = infa.select_one('.usertext.mr-1').text
# prdedstoiashee = soup1.select_one('.text-xs-center.text-center.mt-3').text.strip()
# return f"{infa1}\n{prdedstoiashee}"
```

except AttributeError:
return 'Логин или пароль введен неверно.'